# How to make sure an Option field in Scala is not None

Tags: scala

I have a list consisting of case classes with the following signature

```
case class Post(Id: Option[String], Type: Option[String], CreationDate: Option[String], Tags: Option[String])
```

when processing the elements of this list, how can I check and make sure that the fields have values and are not `None`?

Comment: This is taken as excerpt from @elm answer. Hope it can improve your approach/design, thus I'm repeating it here: "Btw. model in question looks a bit strange for me. What is it worth to model a class with all the fields optional (even Id). I'd suggest to re-thing the model first, while it smells like: Post(id: String, ... //maybe options) should be right thing to do and then on usage side just use Option[Post] and directly call .isDefined". See whole conversation for details.

Answer (score 4):

```
val posts: List[Post] = ???

def isCompletePost(p: Post): Boolean = p match {
  case Post(Some(_), Some(_), Some(_), Some(_)) => true
  case _                                        => false
}

val completePosts = posts filter isCompletePost
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a case class, you can iterate over its values, and require *for each* to hold a condition; hence

```
myPosts.forall( _.productIterator.forall( _ != None ))
```

requires each post in the list and for each value, no one is `None`.

Comment: It is doable but not preferred way, you are loosing all the typesafety provided by compiler. When somebody will change the type of fields to e.g. Either or another worse some of them to any sort of collection, like Seq. You can miss the needed refactoring. Btw. model in question looks a bit strange for me. What is it worth to model a class with all the fields optional (even Id). I'd suggest to re-thing the model first, while it smells like: Post(id: String, ... //maybe options) should be right thing to do and then on usage side just use Option[Post] and directly call .isDefined

Comment: @Teliatko agree, type information is lost; also agree model is improvable, at least for `id`.

Comment: I've just tried to warn before consequences of such approach/design :)